# Spec for Clojure regex literals

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, clojure.spec

One of the keys in my maps should hold a Clojure(Script) regular expression, a [regex literal](http://www.lispcast.com/clojure-regex). How do I write a Spec which both matches and can generate such?

Note that this question is not about matching a string expressed by a regular expression, but matching the regular expression itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clojure regex literals on the JVM are instances of `java.util.regex.Pattern` and a spec which both matches and generates regular expressions can be seen below.

```
(spec/def ::stregex
  (spec/with-gen
    #(instance? java.util.regex.Pattern %)
    #(gen/fmap re-pattern (spec/gen string?))))
```